# Avoid not needed requests on Saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have a redux-saga function bounded to '@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE' action. the main problem is that every time the user switches between sections there are tons of unnecessary requests because the data already exists in the store.

```
export function* resourcesSwitcher(action) {
    yield put(getConstants());

    switch (section) {
        case '/dashboard':
        yield all([
            put((check) ? getDate() : addDate(date)),
        ]);
        break;
        case '/apps':
        yield all([
            put(getApps({ filter })),
            put(getPlatforms()),
            roleId >= C.roles.User && put(getKeys({ filter })),
        ]);
        break;
        case '/rules':
        yield all([
            put(getRules({ filter: rulesFilter })),
            put(getKeys({ filter })),
            put(getDevices()),
        ]);
        break;
        case '/revenues':
        yield all([
            put((check) ? getDate() : addDate(date)),
            put(getApps()),
            put(getAccounts()),
        ]);
        break;
        case '/keys':
        yield all([
            put(getKeys({ filter })),
            put(getApps()),
        ]);
        break;
        default:
    }
}

export default function* root() {
    yield all([
        takeLatest('FETCH', resourcesSwitcher),
    ]);
}
```

I want to add some checker function to be sure that the store[value] is not empty so saga can avoid the call. f.e not requesting constants or Apps on every LOCATION_CHANGE action if the data already exists.

```
const getStore = (state) => state;
const store = yield select(getStore);

function* checker(value) {
    console.log('checking store', value);
    let result = null;
    let method = null;
    switch (value) {
    case 'apps':
        method = getApps();
        break;
    case 'keys':
        method = getKeys();
        break;
    case 'constants':
        method = getConstants();
        break;
    default:
        result = (store[value].data.length) ? null : method;
    }
    if (result) return yield put(result);
    console.log('prefetched, avoided');
    return {};
}
```

I do not fully master redux-saga so might be a better way to implement this "cache".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For cases like this I typically write a selector and just check that before I make an api call. Something like:

```
// adapt this selector based on your store structure and conditions
// for fetching data again
const shouldFetchConstantsSelector = state => state.constants.data.length > 0;

export function* resourcesSwitcher(action) {
    const shouldFetchConstants = yield select(shouldFetchConstantsSelector);
    if (shouldFetchConstants) {
      yield put(getConstants());
    }
    ... etc.
}
```